# How to pull out logged coefficient from a regression? R

Tags: r, function, variables

I have a regression output in R from a panel regression (using plm) and to plot the results I need to pull out some coefficients. I have lags in the model. When I search for the structure of the data I get this:

```
 str(ide2$model)

 $ lag(depvar, 1): 'pseries' Named num  1 1 1 1 1.74 ...
```

however, when I try to call $lag(depvar, 1) (which is technically the name of the variable in the object) I get the following error message:

```
ide2$model$lag(depvar,1)
```

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

Is there a way to get around the issue and call a variable that is lagged from the model object? 
Thank you!

Comment: If you try `ide2$model$lag` or `ide2$model[["lag"]]`, what do you get?

Comment: `ide2$model[["lag(depvar, 1)"]]`